# HTML not showing after PHP

Tags: php, html

I'm currently trying to finetune a login script, only I have one small issue- the HTML isn't showing. I tried to put the HTML in front of the PHP, but the 
**session_start();** depends on the fact that it's at the top, so if I put the HTML before the PHP, the HTML renders, but the PHP is invalid. This is normal- however, the fact that the HTML doesn't show isn't.

Just to clarify, this is a .php document.

FULL CODE:

```
<?php
ob_start();
session_start();
require_once 'dbconnect.php';

// it will never let you open index(login) page if session is set
if ( isset($_SESSION['user'])!="" ) {
header("Location: home.php");
exit;
}

if( isset($_POST['btn-login']) ) { 

$email = $_POST['email'];
$upass = $_POST['pass'];

$email = strip_tags(trim($email));
$upass = strip_tags(trim($upass));

$password = hash('sha256', $upass); // password hashing using SHA256

$res=mysql_query("SELECT userId, userName, userPass FROM users WHERE userEmail='$email'");

$row=mysql_fetch_array($res);

$count = mysql_num_rows($res); // if uname/pass correct it returns must be 1 row

if( $count == 1 && $row['userPass']==$password ) {
 $_SESSION['user'] = $row['userId'];
 header("Location: home.php");
 } else {
 $errMSG = "Wrong Credentials, Try again...";
 }
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Login & Registration System</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://demos.codingcage.com/signup-login/style.css" type="text/css" />



</head>
<body>

<div class="container">

<div id="login-form">
<form method="post" autocomplete="off">

 <div class="col-md-12">

 <div class="form-group">
 <h2 class="">Sign In.</h2>
 </div>

 <div class="form-group">
  <hr />
  </div>

<?php
if ( isset($errMSG) ) {    
?>
<div class="form-group">
         <div class="alert alert-danger">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></span> <?php echo $errMSG; 
?>
            </div>
         </div>
<?php
}
?>

        <div class="form-group">
         <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span></span>
         <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Email" required />
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
         <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></span></span>
         <input type="password" name="pass" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Password" required />
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
         <hr />
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
         <button type="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-primary" name="btn-login">Sign In</button>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
         <hr />
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
         <a href="register.php">Sign Up Here...</a>
        </div>

     </div>

 </form>
 </div> 

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The problem seems to be from "require_once 'dbconnect.php';" if you remove it does everything works fine? Pls post the content of the dbconnect.php but don't forget to rewrite the db password or any other information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

put this at the top..

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

and it will tell you what the error is so people on stack overflow don't have to guess..

also, mysql_* functions are deprecated. if you want to get hacked, that's cool. if not, maybe look into PDO instead.

---

**EDIT**

**I can't comment on the other answer yet so I'll just say here that `isset` returns a boolean. Comparing a boolean to an empty string with `==` has the exact same effect as comparing it with `false` ...this is unconventional, but it's not incorrect and it's certainly not causing any kind of error.**

Proof: https://3v4l.org/vr8UU

The other answer is wrong.

Comment: I realize that they're deprecated- I'm currently in the process of upgrading this older script to mysqli_, but first I'd like to fix it. No point in taking the time to upgrade it if it won't work one way or the other

Comment: "Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function error_erporting() in /srv/disk12/2189518/www/goshoes.tk/index.php:2 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /srv/disk12/2189518/www/goshoes.tk/index.php on line 2"                                                                                                            Line 2 being "error_erporting(E_ALL);"

Comment: i can't comment on the other answer yet so I'll just say here that `isset` returns a boolean. Comparing a boolean to an empty string with `!=` has the exact same effect as doing `!isset()` ...this is unconventional, but it's not iccorect and it's certainly not causing any kind of error.

Answer (score 1):

`if (isset($_SESSION['user'])!="" ) {` this is not how `isset()` works.

Use: `if (isset($_SESSION['user'])) {` instead.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php

And remove the `exit`. It isn't necessary at this place.

Comment: I switched it out- still no change.